# Titanium module - life cycle events not called

Tags: module, titanium, appcelerator, android-lifecycle

I am building a Titanium module for the Android platform and I want to use the life cycle events of the module (i.e. onDestroy, onPause, etc). I tried to use them by overriding these life cycle events in the module class like this:

```
@Kroll.module(name="custom", id="vub.ac.be.custom")
public class CustomModule extends KrollModule {
    private static final String TAG = "customModule";


    @Kroll.onAppCreate
    public static void onAppCreate(TiApplication app) {

    }

    private void destroyServices(){
        //...       
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Activity activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "STOPPING");
        destroyServices();
        super.onStop(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(Activity activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[MODULE LIFECYCLE EVENT] pause");
        super.onPause(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(Activity activity) {       
        Log.d(TAG, "[MODULE LIFECYCLE EVENT] resume");  
        super.onResume(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(Activity activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[MODULE LIFECYCLE EVENT] destroy");
        destroyService();
        super.onDestroy(activity);
    }
}
```

but when I opening and closing the application, these life cycle events are never called. Does anybody know how to use them, because only if I can use them I will be able to build the module I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the origin of my problems: inline link moddevguide

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/moddevguide/mobile/android/src/ti/moddevguide/ModdevguideModule.java

on line 72 they describe the following:

```
// Lifecycle

// NOTES:
//
// 1. Modules are created in the root context
// 2. Using navBarHidden (or fullscreen or modal) causes the window, when opened, to run in a new Android Activity. 
// 3. The root context/activity will be stopped when a new activity is launched
// 4. Lifecycle notifications will NOT be received while the root activity is stopped.
```

I run the module in an application that uses navBarHidden, so as described a new android activity wil be started and the root activity is stopped. Whenever the root activity is stopped, the lifecycle notifications are received. Can anyone confirm this and does anybody know how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What version of SDK are you using? On 3.3.0 lifecycle callbacks is calling regardless to navigation bar hidden.